# how to create next condition in same value in node js

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I have problems in my code

value in my json

```
 [
  {
    "title": "a",
    "detail": {
     "descript": "test"
    }
  },     
  {
    "title": "b",
    "detail": {
     "descript": "test1"
   }
 },
 {
    "title": "c",
    "detail": {
     "descript": "test2"
    }
  }
]
```

My model api

```
router.post('/newscreate', function(req, res){
var queryng = req.body || req.body.query;
if (queryng){
   for (i=0; i<queryng.length; i++){
       var loop = queryng[i];
       if (loop){
          if (loop.title != 'a'){                 
              console.log('true', loop.title);
          }else{
              console.log('false', loop.title);
              //event if value same 'a' then post title b and title c
          }
       } 
    }
}
});
```

I have tired one day just to do this condition, can anyone help correct this code?
thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you saying you want to skip duplicate titles? Skip a specific title? Something else?

Comment: This looks wrong for starters `var queryng = req.body || req.body.query;`. Do you mean `var queryng = req.body && req.body.query;` perhaps?

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah i want to skip duplicate titles and if duplicate title is passed then do post title b and c. how to create this condition?

Comment: @skirtle I do not know, but it's true for me, is it really wrong to start from  var queryng = req.body || req.body.query; ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The `||` operator only evaluates the second operand if the first operand is falsey. So if `req.body` is an object it'll ignore the second part but if `req.body` is null it'll try to access `req.body.query` and bomb out. I'm guessing you mean `&&` rather than `||` but it's difficult to tell without knowing how exactly you're passing the data to the server. It might help if you include the code you use to make the request.

Comment: @skirtle wow okay it's really helps,  i will change the code thanks for the help

Comment: If you need to track through all the titles, not just sequential ones, you probably want an object with the titles as keys. Or you can iterate the array again, up to where you currently are.